# array_push multiple values based on variable?

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

I am trying to create an array with values repeated according to some variables.  In this scenario: `$slipszero = "2"` & `$slipsone = "1"`, and those values can change.
This is my code as of now:

```
$problist = array();
    foreach ($rows as $value) {
        if ($value['f_count'] == 0) {
            $placeholder = rtrim(str_repeat($value["uid"] . ',', $slipszero), ', ') ;
            array_push($problist, $placeholder);
            // The above array_push should act just like:
            array_push($problist, $value['uid'], $value['uid']);
        } elseif ($value['f_count'] == 1) {
            $placeholder = rtrim(str_repeat($value["uid"] . ',', $slipsone), ', ') ;
            array_push($problist, $placeholder);
        } elseif ($value['f_count'] >= 2) {
            $problist[] = $value['uid'];
        }
    }
```

So, starting with this array:

```
Array ( 
 [0] => Array ( [uid] => 105 [f_count] => 0 ) 
 [1] => Array ( [uid] => 106 [f_count] => 1 ) 
 [2] => Array ( [uid] => 107 [f_count] => 0 ) 
 [3] => Array ( [uid] => 108 [f_count] => 1 ) 
 [4] => Array ( [uid] => 109 [f_count] => 2 ) 
)
```

I'd like to end up with this array:

```
array(15) { 
[0] => string(3) "105" 
[1] => string(3) "105" 
[2] => string(3) "106" 
[3] => string(3) "107" 
[4] => string(3) "107" 
[5] => string(3) "108" 
[6] => string(3) "109"
}
```

Instead, I'm getting this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => 105,105 
[1] => 106 
[2] => 107,107 
[3] => 108
[4] => 109
)
```

Taking care of a newborn has shot my brain, because I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `// The above array_push should act just like: ... `  Why?

Comment: why you don't use for ? `for ( ; $i<$slipsone;$i++ ) //array push` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($array as $subarray) {
    $i = 1; // default value
    if ($subarray["f_count"] === 0)
        $i = $slipszero;
    if ($subarray["f_count"] === 1)
        $i = $slipsone;
    while ($i--)
        $newArray[] = (string)$subarray["uid"];
}
```

This is adding `$i` times the string to the array where `$i` is depending on `$subarray["f_count"]`.

Comment: For efficiency sake, I was trying to use `push_array()` rather than `$array[] =` whenever inserting more than one row.

Comment: @David `array_push` is not more efficient when you use only one single argument. It's slower than `$array[]`. (And here you only can push the values one per one)

Comment: Right, which is why I specified "whenever inserting more than one row."

Comment: @David "And here (in this specific case) you only can push the values one per one" I just said. There exists ways with `call_user_func_array` if you really want to, but this is even more inefficient.

Comment: OK, I now see what you meant by that.

One issue though: `===` ought to be `==`.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$problist = array();
    foreach ($rows as $value) {
        if ($value['f_count'] == 0) {
            for($i=0;$i<$slipszero;$i++)
                array_push($problist, $value["uid"];);

        } elseif ($value['f_count'] == 1) {
            for($i=0;$i<$slipsone;$i++)
               array_push($problist, $value["uid"];);
        } elseif ($value['f_count'] >= 2) {
            $problist[] = $value['uid'];
        }
    }
```